# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax Error:

Tags: mysql

Here, I am getting error in mysql.
My query:

```
INSERT INTO shipping_boxes(ship_method,order_id,box_id, rate,signature,weight, length, width,height, value,markupPercentage, insured) VALUES("FedEx - Ground","15569","88888","480","0","36.3","16","12","12","96","5","1")("FedEx - Ground","15569","88888","480","0","36.3","16","12","12","96","5","1");
```

Comment: You have 2 sets of values. Has to be one.

Comment: You're not providing enough information. You may want to provide the table definition for the *shipping_boxes* table.

Comment: What about if I am getting two set of values?  Then how can I insert into database?

Comment: then you need 2 queris

Comment: @bub No, you can actually do it in one. What we need to see from Viral Bhoot is ***THE ACTUAL ERROR MESSAGE*** along with the table definition for `shipping_boxes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you pasting the values twice?

The query should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO shipping_boxes(ship_method, order_id, box_id, rate, signature, weight, length, width, height, value, markupPercentage, insured)
VALUES("FedEx - Ground", "15569", "88888", "480", "0", "36.3", "16", "12", "12", "96", "5", "1");
```

I would be more clear if you shared the table definition and the error details.

Comment: What about if I am getting two set of values? Then how can I insert into database?

Comment: for inserting 2 records, you can write 2 insert statements:   INSERT INTO shipping_boxes(ship_method, order_id, box_id, rate, signature, weight, length, width, height, value, markupPercentage, insured)
VALUES("FedEx - Ground", "15569", "88888", "480", "0", "36.3", "16", "12", "12", "96", "5", "1");   INSERT INTO shipping_boxes(ship_method, order_id, box_id, rate, signature, weight, length, width, height, value, markupPercentage, insured)
VALUES("FedEx - Ground","15569","88888","480","0","36.3","16","12","12","96","5","1");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data types are but you have expressed all your numbers as strings. 
If your database has integer as a datatype this might not help.